# fwrite dynamic values with commas to excel

Tags: php, fwrite

I inherited a site and need some help. There is a fwrite() function in php that writes a csv file using information from a database. One of the things I want to be written is a product description. The descriptions all have commas, and when the csv sees the commas, it starts a new cell breaking the description up into many different cells. I would prefer if the entire description was in one cell. I can get it to do that if I str_replace() the commas to something else, so that part of the code isn't the issue.

What's the best way (if it's even possible) to write a value that contains commas to a csv file?

Right now, it looks something like this:

```
$orderrecord = '"'.$row['product_description_that_has_commas'].'"';

        $orderrecord .= "\r\n";
        $ofl = fopen($exportordersfilename, 'ab');
        fwrite($ofl, $orderrecord);
        fclose($ofl);
```

Comment: Include the description between the " and the commas will not create problems.

Comment: Do you mean like, $row["product_description"]?

Comment: Yes. I've just tested opening the csv with openoffice and all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the PHP function called [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.fputcsv.php).

```php
<?php

$fh = fopen('file', 'w');
fputcsv($fh, array($description_with_quotes, 'field_two', '...'));
fclose($fh);
```